# Why do i get the segmentation fault (Nested structures)?

Tags: c, data-structures

I am having the segmentation fault issue for about 3 hours ago and I don't really figure it out why. I am trying to assign memory dinamically to terminos(struct) but I can't. I hope you can help me

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    typedef struct termino
    {
      int exponente;
      float cociente;
    } termino;

    typedef struct polinomio
    {

  termino* polinomio;
  int size;
} polinomio;

main()
{


int size_;
  termino* terminos;
  polinomio *polinomio_;
  polinomio_ = malloc(sizeof(polinomio));
  printf("%d",(sizeof(polinomio_)*2));

  printf("Bienvenido al cálculo de operaciones usando 1 polinomio.\n");
  printf("Ingrese la cantidad de términos que tendrá el polinomio.");  
  scanf("%d",size_);
  //assigning memory for terminos.
  terminos =(termino*) malloc(sizeof(termino) * size_);
```

Comment: `main()`--> `int main(void)`

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Also, now sounds like a good time to get familiar with a debugger.  "I have a segfault and can't figure out why" with no additional information is not a valid question.  If you are using `gcc`, please change your command line to `gcc -Wall -Werror` before continuing. If you are using Visual Studio **pay attention** to any compiler warnings being emitted. They're there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is

```
 scanf("%d",size_);
```

change to

```
 scanf("%d",&size_);
```

because , `scanf()` expects a pointer-to-data type argument.

Related, from `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2, (*emphasis mine*)

> `d`
>
> Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as
>   expected for the subject sequence of the `strtol()` function with the value `10` for the base argument. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer.**

Apart from that,

1. The recommended signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. Correct format specifier for `sizeof` is `%zu`.
3. [Please do not cast the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3137699)